# How to modify lambda function to use with an if-statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, lambda

I stuck in the middle with the problem of how to create four new rows in a dataframe which would be populated by 1 and 0 on a certain condition. I decided to use Lambda functons but instead of numbers it returns `<function <lambda> at 0x000002B0251C7700>`.

What am I doing wrong and how is it possible to fix it?

This is the code I use:

```
df["1_quarter"] = lambda row : 1 if (df["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * df["stage_y"])) else 0
df["2_quarter"] = lambda row : 1 if (df["stage_x"] > (0.25 * df["stage_y"]) and df[stage_x] <= (0.5 * df["stage_y"])) else 0
df["3_quarter"] = lambda row : 1 if (df["stage_x"] > (0.5 * df["stage_y"]) and df[stage_x] <= (0.75 * df["stage_y"])) else 0
df["4_quarter"] = lambda row : 1 if (df["stage_x"] > (0.75 * df["stage_y"]) and df[stage_x] <= (df["stage_y"])) else 0
```

Comment: [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)s are *expressions* that create anonymous functions (not call them). Your code is only doing the former.

Comment: `lambda` only defined function but it doesn't execute it . You may have to use `lambda` in `apply()` to execute this function on all rows in dataframe. Or you may need to use `np.where( your_if, 1, 0 )`

Comment: because `int(True) gives `1` and `int(False)` gives '0` so maybe you could use `df["1_quarter"] =  (df["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * df["stage_y"])).astype(int)` But I would rather keep `True/False` instead of `1/0`

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` only defines function but it doesn't execute it.

You may have to use it with `.apply()` to run on every row - but in `lambda` you should use `row[...]` instead of `df[...]`

```
func1 = lambda row : 1 if (row["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * row["stage_y"])) else 0

df["1_quarter"] = df.apply(func1, axis=1)
```

or in one line but less readable

```
df["1_quarter"] = df.apply( (lambda row : 1 if (row["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * row["stage_y"])) else 0), axis=1)
```

---

Eventually you could use fact that `int(True)` gives `1` and `int(False)` gives `0`
and inside `if ...` you have expression which gives `True` or `False`.
And this doesn't need `lambda`.

```
df["1_quarter"] = (df["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * df["stage_y"])).astype(int)
```

You may do the same with `numpy.where( expression, value_for_True, value_for_False )`

```
df["1_quarter"] = np.where(df["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * df["stage_y"]), 1, 0)
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'stage_x': [1,2,3,4], 
    'stage_y': [4,5,6,16], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

func1 = lambda row : 1 if (row["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * row["stage_y"])) else 0
df["1_quarter_A"] = df.apply(func1, axis=1)

df["1_quarter_B"] = (df["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * df["stage_y"])).astype(int)

df["1_quarter_C"] = np.where(df["stage_x"] <= (0.25 * df["stage_y"]), 1, 0)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   stage_x  stage_y  1_quarter_A  1_quarter_B  1_quarter_C
0        1        4            1            1            1
1        2        5            0            0            0
2        3        6            0            0            0
3        4       16            1            1            1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. The first variant worked amazing. And thanks for the two other variants.

Comment: theoretically versions without `apply()` should work faster because they should use C/C++ code with execute functions at once on all data. But for small data it can work the same speed.